# Recurrence relation to calculate encodings

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming, recurrence

I recently stumbled upon a nice problem and even after a substantial time cant seem to figure out the recurrence relation.

Here is the problem statement:

```
A message containing letters from A-Z is being encoded to numbers using 
the following mapping:
'A' -> 1
'B' -> 2
...
'Z' -> 26
Given an encoded message containing digits, determine the total number of ways to decode it.
```

So for example:

```
if the given input is 121 we can have three encodings
1. ABA (1-->A, 2-->B)
2. LA  (12 -->L, 1-->A)
3. AU  (1--A, 21--U)
All I was able to achieve was the base cases:
if len(S) == 1:
    if S == "0":
       return 0
    return 1
if len(S) == 2:
   if int(S) > 26:
       return 1
   return 2
```

Apart from the base case, I cant seem to figure out the recurrence relation. Any help would be grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Say we are currently at index `i` in an array of digits `a[n]`. The number of digits to the right of and including the current is `n - i`. Here are the cases we need to check:

- If `n - i <= 0` then return 1 (because there is only one way to arrange zero digits).
- If `n - i > 1`:

  - If `a[i]` and `a[i + 1]` give a number in the range `[10, 26]`, add number of combinations starting from `i + 2` (i.e. we consume these two digits).
- Must then either have `n - i = 1` or two digits which are out of range, so add number of combinations starting from `i + 1` (i.e. consume one digit).

Pseudocode:

```
def countCombos(a[n], i):
   if i >= n: return 1
   two <- 0
   if n - i > 1:
      if a[i] == 1 || (a[i] == 2 && a[i + 1] <= 6):
         two <- countCombos(a, i + 2)
   return two + countCombos(a, i + 1)
```

I'll leave it to you to implement memoization.

Comment: thanks mate. I get it now. But I got really frustrated last night since I couldnt figure out the recurrence relation. Any tips as to how to go thinking about the recurrence relations in problems like these?

Comment: I think that is too broad as a question; however the defining feature of DP is finding a sub-problem which can be solved in the exact same way. The cases determine how the state is updated and which subproblem(s) to solve. Not sure if that helps; you probably knew the above already.

Comment: Finally I hade some time. It seems that we are counting extra here. For example, for string "12" the answer should be 2 (AB, L) but the relation gives three.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment assume that `s` doesn't contain a zero; if it does, `f(s)=0`.

There is precisely one way to decode a string of length 1: `f(s)=1` if `|s|=1`. And for the empty string---that is the string of length zero---we set `f(s)=0`.

Now, for the recurrence, we start at the left-end and if `s[1..2] <= 26` we have two ways of interpreting it: either as `decode(s[1]), decode(s[2])` or as `decode(s[1..2])`. Otherwise, if `s[1..2]>26` there's only one choice.

This leads naturally to the following recurrence:

`count(s)
    if |s| <= 1 then
        return |s|
    else
        v = 0 
        if s[1..2] <= 26:
            v = f(s[1:])
        return v + f(s[2:])`

Obviously you'd want to do some memoization in practice to avoid exponential running time.

As a side-note, observe that when `s` has the property that for any `1<=i<|s|` you have `s[i..i+1] <= 26` the recurrence is precisely the Fibonacci recurrence (shifted slightly).